# Are Entry Controlled Loop and Pretest Loop the same?

Tags: c++, loops

I have an assessment asking about the type of Loop wherein it checks/validates the value before doing such action. And I am not sure if Entry Controlled Loops is the same as Pretest Loops.

Comment: ***..such action*** What action?

Comment: When statements in the loop body are executed.

Comment: I would guess they are the same. `for` and `while` loops are pretest or entry-controlled, `do-while` loop is exit-controlled.